# Migrating from SVN to GIT with tags/trunk/branches/release with a extra folder

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn, tortoisegit

I have SVN project with the below directory structure

```
root
    |-->branches
    |-->trunk
        --> file 1
        --> file 2
    |-->release
        --> file 1
        --> file 2
    |-->tags
        |-->tag1
        |-->tag2
        |-->tagN
```

The problem with moving from SVN to GIT is
I can map

```
SVN      to   GIT
branches --  branches
tags     --  tags
trunk    --  trunk
release  --  ??????
```

How can I map **release** folder to a GIT folder

Comment: In Git terms, `release` appears to be another branch. It just doesn't live in the `branches` folder. You aren't going to want to use such a one-to-one mapping of folders when converting to Git. A tool like `git-svn` should be able to create proper Git branches from both the contents of `branches` and from `release`.

Comment: If I move release to tags and migrate to GIT, I am unable to preserve the log details and svn:externals

Comment: Going forward, a release should probably be a tag, but for the purposes of the migration, you should treat it as a branch.

Comment: Thanks... I think thats the best way for the migration with a loss of some links on comments and releases...

Is there a way possible to move all  the svn-externals links to git-submodules? There are subfolders in each repositpry linking to other subfoders of repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the should be also tags. It depends mainly in how you used them. Take a look to the Atlassian tutorial about migrating from Subversion to Git. It's quite straight and clear: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview.
You can experiment, look what you get and if you don't like you can always start over.